# React Drag and Drop Cursor Change

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I've built a simple drag-and-drop function in React. There are 2 columns that `div`s can be dragged between and a third is not allowed. The CSS dynamically changes if one is to drag over the `noDrop` div. The last part, however, is that I'd like the cursor to also change to `cursor: not-allowed`. All of the CSS works except for this line. How can I get the cursor to change?

Edit: I have tried moving the `cursor: not-allowed` into the "thing" div, but it didn't work either. I've updated the code to reflect this.

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-cursor-question-tiv71?file=/src/Dnd.js

Dnd.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Dnd.scss";

export default function Dnd() {
  const initialItems = [
    { id: 1, group: "group1", value: "drag 1" },
    { id: 2, group: "group1", value: "drag 2" },
    { id: 3, group: "group1", value: "drag 3" }
  ];
  const groups = ["group1", "group2", "noDrop"];
  const [items, setItems] = useState(initialItems);
  const [dragData, setDragData] = useState({});
  const [noDrop, setNoDrop] = useState("");


  const handleDragStart = (e, id, group) => {
    setDragData({ id: id, initialGroup: group });
  };

  const handleDragEnter = (e, group) => {
    if (group === "noDrop") {
      setNoDrop("noDrop");
    }
  };

  const handleDragLeave = (e) => {
    setNoDrop("");
  };

  const handleDragOver = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  const changeCategory = (itemId, group) => {
    const newItems = [...items];
    newItems[itemId - 1].group = group;
    setItems([...newItems]);
  };

  const handleDrop = (e, group) => {
    setNoDrop("");
    const selected = dragData.id;
    if (group === "noDrop") {
      console.log("nuh uh");
    } else {
      changeCategory(selected, group);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="groups">
        {groups.map((group) => (
          <div
            className={`${
              group === "noDrop" && noDrop === "noDrop" ? noDrop : "group"
            }`}
            onDragOver={handleDragOver}
            onDragEnter={(e) => handleDragEnter(e, group)}
            onDrop={(e) => handleDrop(e, group)}
            onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
            key={group}
          >
            <h1 className="title">{group}</h1>
            <div>
              {items
                .filter((item) => item.group === group)
                .map((item) => (
                  <div
                    key={item.id}
                    id={item.id}
                    className={`${
                      group === "noDrop" && noDrop === "noDrop"
                        ? "notAllowed"
                        : "thing"
                    }`}                    draggable
                    onDragStart={(e) => handleDragStart(e, item.id, group)}
                  >
                    {item.value}
                  </div>
                ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Dnd.scss

```
.groups {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  

  .group {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 16rem;
    background-color: green;

    .title{
      color: white;
      padding: 0;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
  }
  .noDrop {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 16rem;
    background-color: red;


    .title{
      color: white;
      padding: 0;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
  }
}


.thing {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px green;
  cursor: grab;
}

.notAllowed {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px green;
  cursor: not-allowed !important;
}
```